# How to improve loop speed without referencing cells VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am running the code below to extract data from worksheets and spit it out, it is very slow, any ideas for speed improvements?

Essentially this loop is to extract data from an array (from a database)

I have done the usual turn off calcs etc, what I am looking for is how to loop without going through the worksheet cells as that is what is taking a long time I think.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
    Set RawDataD1WS = PnLWB.Worksheets("Raw_Data_D1")
    Dim VarBunker As Variant
    
    
For i = LBound(VarBunker, 1) To UBound(VarBunker, 1)

    For k = LBound(VarBunker, 1) To UBound(VarBunker, 2)
    BunkerD1WS.Cells(k + 2, i + 1) = VarBunker(i, k)
    Next k

Next i
```

Comment: Is `VarBunker` an array you got from using `GetRows()` ?

Comment: yes it is, this is the get rows bit: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "SELECT [External BA],[Origin],[DeliveredQuantity Total] from [Bunker_Deliveries$]"
    rs.Open strSQL, cn
    If rs.EOF = False Then
        VarBunker = rs.GetRows
    End If
    rs.Close

Comment: A 2-D array from GetRows is "flipped" (as you know) so the quickets way to write it to the sheet is to use a function to transpose the array in memory and then place it on the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2-D array from `GetRows` is "flipped" (as you know) so the quickest way to write it to the sheet is to use a function to transpose the array in memory and then place it on the sheet.  You could use `Application.Transpose()` but that does have a limit on the size of the array it can deal with, so it's better to have your own function so you don't have the think about that.

```vb
Sub TestDrop()

    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection, arr
    Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset, strPath, n, ws As Worksheet

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    
    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Data Source=" & strPath
    
    Set oRS = oConn.Execute("select * from [TABLE1]")
    
    arr = oRS.GetRows()
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ws.Range("I1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2) + 1).Value = arr ' "flipped"
    
    arr = XPose(arr)
    
    ws.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2) + 1).Value = arr ' transposed
    

End Sub

'Transpose an array
Function XPose(arr)
    Dim lbr As Long, ubr As Long, lbc As Long, ubc As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim arrOut
    lbr = LBound(arr, 1)
    ubr = UBound(arr, 1)
    lbc = LBound(arr, 2)
    ubc = UBound(arr, 2)
    ReDim arrOut(lbc To ubc, lbr To ubr)
    For r = lbr To ubr
        For c = lbc To ubc
            arrOut(c, r) = arr(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    XPose = arrOut
End Function
```

Comment: Tried this method, works great! thanks for the shared knowledge !

Answer (score 1):

### Write a 2D Array to a Range

- If you're sure the array is 0-based, you can remove the `LBound`s.
- If you're sure the array is 1-based, you can remove the `LBound + 1`s.

```vb
Set RawDataD1WS = PnLWB.Worksheets("Raw_Data_D1")
Dim VarBunker As Variant ' redim it and add some values to it

Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(VarBunker, 1) - LBound(VarBunker, 1) + 1
Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(VarBunker, 2) - LBound(VarBunker, 2) + 1

BunkerD1WS.Range("A2").Resize(rCount, cCount).Value = VarBunker
```

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

**Do not user array.**
Arrays have limitations with ranges. You cannot insert 10000 rows to an array.
Instead do the following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=false
Application.Calculate=XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
Sheet1.EnableCalculation=False
' Your code
' ...
' Restore to defaults after processing
```

Comment: "You cannot insert 10000 rows to an array"  - that's just wrong.  Where are you getting that from?